# How do I replace items on one DataFrame with items from other DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['bumgm001', 'lestj001', 
    'tanam001', 'hellj001', 'chacj001']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'playerID': ['bumgama01', 'lestejo01',
     'tanakama01', 'hellije01', 'chacijh01'], 
     'retroID': ['bumgm001', 'lestj001', 'tanam001', 'hellj001', 'chacj001']})
```

OR

```
   df                                  df1
    ID                      playerID       retroID
'bumgm001'                  'bumgama01'     'bumgm001'
'lestj001'                  'lestejo01'     'lestj001'
'tanam001'                  'tanakama01'    'tanam001'
'hellj001'                  'hellije01'     'hellj001'
'chacj001'                  'chacijh01'     'chacj001'
```

Now, my actual DataFrames are a little more complicated than this, but I simplified it here so it's clearer what I'm trying to do.

I would like to take all of the `ID`'s in `df` and replace them with the corresponding `playerID`'s in `df1`.

My final `df` should look like this:

```
   df                                 
**ID**                  
'bumgama01'     
'lestejo01'    
'tanakama01'    
'hellije01'     
'chacijh01'
```

I have tried to do it using the following method:

```
for row in df.itertuples(): #row[1] == the retroID column

    playerID = df1.loc[df1['retroID']==row[1], 'playerID']]

    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'].replace(to_replace=
    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'], value=playerID)
```

The code seems to run just fine.  But my `retroID`'s in `df` have been changed to `NaN` rather than the proper `playerIDs`.

This strikes me as a datatype problem, but I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to diagnose any further.

EDIT:

Unfortunately, I made my example too simplistic. I edited to better represent the issue I'm having. I'm trying to look up the item from one DataFrame in a second DataFrame, then I want to replace the item from the first Dataframe with an item from the corresponding row of the second Dataframe.  The columns DO NOT have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second dataframe as a dictionary for replacement:

```
to_replace = df1.set_index('retroID')['playerID'].to_dict()
df['retroID'].replace(to_replace, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, this is what you want:

```
df['ID'] = df1['playerID']
```

If data is not in order (row 1 from df is not the same as row 1 from df1) then use

```
df['ID']=df1.set_index('retroID').reindex(df['ID'])['playerID'].values
```

Credit to **Wen** for second approach

Output

```
      ID
0   bumgama01
1   lestejo01
2  tanakama01
3   hellije01
4   chacijh01
```

Let me know if it's correct

Comment: This works _only_ if the players in both dataframes are listed in the same order.

Comment: that's why I said 'according to the example', otherwise it's necessary to create the dataframe with the retroID as the index but OP may not want to go that way

Comment: Let me fix for you , `df['retroID']=df1.set_index('retroID').reindex(df['retroID'])['playerID'].values`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I should have specified, my columns do not have the same names.  So I have to do it by matching the items.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out a solution.  As it turns out, my problem was a type problem.  I updated my code from:

```
for row in df.itertuples(): #row[1] == the retroID column

    playerID = df1.loc[df1['retroID']==row[1], 'playerID']]

    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'].replace(to_replace=
    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'], value=playerID)
```

to:

```
for row in df.itertuples(): #row[1] == the retroID column

    playerID = df1.loc[df1['retroID']==row[1], 'playerID']].values[0]

    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'].replace(to_replace=
    df.loc[df['ID']==row[1], 'ID'], value=playerID)
```

This works because "playerID" is now a scalar object(thanks to .values[0]) rather than some other datatype which is not compatible with a DataFrame.